# Prevent item from shrinking

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to make a simple popup with variable height which will vertically centered in case it is smaller than viewport and will not be shrinked when it bigger than viewport. Here is sample code:

```css
.flex-container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
.flex-child {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.item {
  height: 160px;
  background-color: #C3C3FC;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-child">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: which is the popup container?
Is there even one in your code, or are you just giving us the "background", as it were?

Comment: Popup container is <div class="flex-child">

Comment: and are you committed to the flex layout, or would a block / table solution be acceptable?

Comment: I already use such solution but i'd prefer to use flexbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `height: 100%` on the flex container is ignored because its containing block (`body`) has `height: auto`.

Therefore, the height of the flex container will be the height of its content, so `justify-content: center` won't be noticeable.

To fix it, you can add a fixed height to `body`:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

But then, if the content is taller than the viewport, the result will be undesirable, because since you have `justify-content: center`, the content will overflow both from above and below, but the scrollbar won't allow to see the above overflow.

So you shouldn't use a fixed height for the flex container, you only need a minimum height, so that it will be allowed to grow if necessary:

```
.flex-container {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto; /* Initial value */
}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.flex-container {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
.flex-child {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.item {
  height: 160px;
  background-color: #C3C3FC;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-child">
    <div class="item">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```